# My class is extent by fragment. I can't get a location

Tags: mapbox-android

Why can't I get location information?
When I extend my class with AppCompatActivity, I can get a location. But when I extent with fragment, I cannot get a location.

```
public class Fragment_Ucuncu extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, PermissionsListener {
    private MapView mapView;
    private PermissionsManager permissionsManager;

    private MapboxMap mapboxMap;

    private final String MAPKIT_API_KEY = "delete";
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Mapbox.getInstance(getActivity() , "delete");
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ucuncu_layout, container, false);

        mapView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(@NonNull MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
                mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS, new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });




        return rootView;

    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull final MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
        Fragment_Ucuncu.this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap;

        mapboxMap.setStyle(new Style.Builder().fromUri("mapbox://styles/mapbox/cjerxnqt3cgvp2rmyuxbeqme7"),
                new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {
                        enableLocationComponent(style);
                    }
                });
    }
    private void enableLocationComponent(@NonNull Style loadedMapStyle) {
// Check if permissions are enabled and if not request
        if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(getActivity())) {

// Get an instance of the component
            LocationComponent locationComponent = mapboxMap.getLocationComponent();

// Activate with options
            locationComponent.activateLocationComponent(
                    LocationComponentActivationOptions.builder(getActivity(), loadedMapStyle).build());

// Enable to make component visible
            locationComponent.setLocationComponentEnabled(true);

// Set the component's camera mode
            locationComponent.setCameraMode(CameraMode.TRACKING);

// Set the component's render mode
            locationComponent.setRenderMode(RenderMode.COMPASS);
        } else {
            permissionsManager = new PermissionsManager(this);
            permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(getActivity());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        permissionsManager.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    @Override
    public void onExplanationNeeded(List<String> permissionsToExplain) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "one", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionResult(boolean granted) {
        if (granted) {
            mapboxMap.getStyle(new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
                @Override
                public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {
                    enableLocationComponent(style);
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "two", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

}
```

I need to show a "mapbox" map in my fragment in the navigation drawer. I couldn't find a sample code for this.
I did this with google map. I can't do with Mapbox. Can you tell me where the problem is?
Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I solved the problem. It works for me.

```
package com.one.qaroco;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsListener;
import com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsManager;

import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsListener;
import com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsManager;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.camera.CameraPosition;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.geometry.LatLng;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.LocationComponent;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.LocationComponentActivationOptions;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.modes.CameraMode;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.modes.RenderMode;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMapOptions;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.Style;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import java.util.List;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

public class FragmentBirinci extends Fragment implements PermissionsListener {
    private MapboxMap mapboxMap;
    private PermissionsManager permissionsManager;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_birinci_layout, container, false);


        // Mapbox access token is configured here. This needs to be called either in your application
        // object or in the same activity which contains the mapview.
        Mapbox.getInstance(getActivity(), getString(R.string.access_token));

        // Create supportMapFragment
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            // Create fragment
            final FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            // Build a Mapbox map
            MapboxMapOptions options = MapboxMapOptions.createFromAttributes(getActivity(), null);
            options.camera(new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(38.899895, -77.03401))
                    .zoom(9)
                    .build());

            // Create map fragment
            mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(options);

            // Add map fragment to parent container
            transaction.add(R.id.location_frag_container, mapFragment, "com.mapbox.map");
            transaction.commit();
        } else {
            mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("com.mapbox.map");
        }

        if (mapFragment != null) {
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(@NonNull MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
                    FragmentBirinci.this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap;
                    mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.OUTDOORS, new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
                        @Override
                        public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {
                            enableLocationComponent(style);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        return rootView;


    }

    @SuppressWarnings( {"MissingPermission"})
    private void enableLocationComponent(@NonNull Style loadedMapStyle) {
        // Check if permissions are enabled and if not request
        if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(getActivity())) {

            // Get an instance of the LocationComponent.
            LocationComponent locationComponent = mapboxMap.getLocationComponent();

            // Activate the LocationComponent
            locationComponent.activateLocationComponent(
                    LocationComponentActivationOptions.builder(getActivity(), loadedMapStyle).build());

            // Enable the LocationComponent so that it's actually visible on the map
            locationComponent.setLocationComponentEnabled(true);

            // Set the LocationComponent's camera mode
            locationComponent.setCameraMode(CameraMode.TRACKING);

            // Set the LocationComponent's render mode
            locationComponent.setRenderMode(RenderMode.NORMAL);
        } else {
            permissionsManager = new PermissionsManager(this);
            permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(getActivity());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        permissionsManager.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    @Override
    public void onExplanationNeeded(List<String> permissionsToExplain) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.user_location_permission_explanation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionResult(boolean granted) {
        if (granted) {
            mapboxMap.getStyle(new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
                @Override
                public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {
                    enableLocationComponent(style);
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.user_location_permission_not_granted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to use the mapbox with a fragment structure in the navigation drawer, there are things to consider.

> 1. Make sure that the imported libraries are "mapbox". Sometimes google libraries can be imported and this causes errors.
>
>    2. Use "getActivity" instead of "this".

[mapbox.com](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/show-a-users-location-on-a-fragment/)

[github mapbox](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/location/LocationComponentFragmentActivity.java)

[github issues](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/issues/1300)

Answer (score 1):

See https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/show-a-users-location-on-a-fragment if you're trying to show the device location puck (the `LocationComponent`) in a map fragment.